# Wolfram Development Platform does not define variables properly

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have a really silly question about *Mathematica*. I'm currently using the Wolfram Development platform, since my Mathematica license has expired. To make life easier, I just want to define some variables which will be used later on.

Now, even for the simplest command like:

```
x = 4
```

Mathematica displays the function $x = 4$, instead of remembering the value $x = 4$. Similarly, if I want to define a variable $a$ as

```
a = x^2 + 4
```

Mathematica then returns as output

```
{{x -> -2i}, {x-> 2i}}
```

So, how can I undo this? I assume I changed something about the settings, though I have no clue what.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  That's not what Mathematica normally does.  Can you you paste both your *precise* input and output here, or show a screenshot?

Comment: I edited my post. Hopefully, my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Could you post a screenshot similar to this one and let us know which input format you're using?

(note: ignore the inaccuracies in my computation, I changed some variables after the fact)